# Rspec selenium not finding data after returning from outside url without setting environment to development

Tags: ruby, rspec, selenium-webdriver

I am having a strange problem with feature testing a paypal authorization with rspec using selenium. When returning to my site from paypal, it claims is cannot find the necessary data with that specific id, but it seems to find another piece of data. I printed the data to the terminal in the test and it WAS there. When I changed my environment in the spec_helper (I know this is bad) to development it worked.

Here is the error:

```
Couldn't find PaypalPreapproval with id=1
```

And here is the code in my controller

```
def show
  user = User.find(params[:user_id])
  preapproval = PaypalPreapproval.find(params[:id])
  preapproval.activate
  send_welcome_message(user) if user.addresses.count == 1
end
```

It is the PaypalPreapproval.find(params[:id]) that is causing the error, although the line above seems to be able to find the User with that id.

This is my temporary fix that works in my spec_helper

```
if Capybara.current_driver == :selenium
  ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= 'development'
else
  ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= 'test'
end
```

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it. When running selenium it randomly generates a port number and fires up that server. Once your test travels outside of your server (an outside url) your return url needs to include the port that is running your test server. I added this to my spec_helper:

```
Capybara.server_port = 4000
```

I already had an environment variable set for my base_url as

```
ENV['BASE_URL'] = "http://localhost:3000"
```

and I just specified it to be

```
ENV['BASE_URL'] = Rails.env.test? ? "http://localhost:4000" : "http://localhost:3000"
```

Hopefully this saves someone else a half-day of debugging.